# Extracting values from hash created by perl JSON::Syck::Load

Tags: json, perl, hashref

I've got a very simple Perl issue that I can't for the life of me figure out.

I'm consuming JSON formatted data from a REST endpoint in a perl script. The data is shaped like this:

```
{
   "ScriptRunning": true
}
```

There's some other stuff, but really all I care about is the ScriptRunning tag. I'm consuming this data using JSON::Syck::Load like so:

```
my $running_scripts = JSON::Syck::Load($output_from_rest_call)
```

(in my current environment it is not possible to get other libraries for CPAN, so I'm stuck with that). All that is working correctly as far as I can tell, I used Data::Dumper to confirm the data looks good:

```
$VAR1 = {
    'ScriptRunning' => 1 # or '' if false
}
```

However, I can't figure out how to actually get the value of 'ScriptRunning'. I've done `print ref $running_scripts` and confirmed that it is a `HASH`, however when I try to index into the hash I'm not getting anything. I've tried the following:

```
my $script_is_running = $running_scripts{'ScriptRunning'};
my $script_is_running = $running_scripts{ScriptRunning};
my $keys_in_running_scripts = keys $running_scripts; # keys_in_running_scripts is empty
my $keys_in_running_scripts = keys %running_scripts; # keys_in_running_scripts is empty
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `use strict;` (and `use warnings;` while you are at it, maybe `use diagnostics;` too, when you are really stuck). As a general rule, **ALWAYS** `use strict;` and `use warnings;` because they prevent problematic code from running and give you some much more helpful output.

You should also read [`perldoc perlreftut`](https://perldoc.pl/perlreftut), which helps explain what you are dealing with.

Your variable `$running_scripts` is not a hash, but a "hash reference", which is an important distinction. When you call `ref` on a real hash, it returns a false value, since it is not a reference.

What you need to do is "dereference" using the [arrow operator](https://perldoc.pl/perlop#The-Arrow-Operator) to get the value.

To get the `keys` call to work, there's a separate syntax for dereferencing.

```
my $script_is_running = $running_scripts->{ScriptRunning};
my @keys_in_running_scripts = keys %{$running_scripts};
```